# Laravel 4 relations with MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, authentication, laravel

I am implementing authentication with Laravel 4 and MongoDB, using https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB as backend.

My User model is like this:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

/**
 * Class User
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 */
class User extends Moloquent implements UserInterface {

    /**
     * Primary key for collection
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'username';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Relationship with role
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Role');
    }

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

}
```

and this is my Role model :

```
/**
 * Class Role
 * @property string name
 */
class Role extends Moloquent {

    /**
     * Primary key for collection
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'name';

    /**
     * Collection name for role
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $collection = 'roles';

    /**
     * Relationship with users
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}
```

As you can see, my users only have `username` and `password` and roles only have `name`.

Problem is, how to save related models? I have tried many ways, as in Laravel Eloqoent documentation, like `$user->role()->save($role)` or `attach` instead of `save`, but only `$role->users()->save($user)` works fine. Why? Shouldn't all of them work? I seem not to understand relationship concepts of Laravel very good.

Another thing is how to get a user's roles? For example :

```
$user = Auth::user();
var_dump($user->role()->get());
```

gives an empty Collection. Shouldn't that give me user's role?

I'm confused a lot!

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** Here is my seeding:

```
class RoleTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run() {
        $adminRole = Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();
        if(empty($adminRole)) {
            Role::create(array(
                'name' => 'admin',
            ));
            Role::create(array(
                'name' => 'superuser',
            ));
            Role::create(array(
                'name' => 'user',
            ));
        }
    }
} 


class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run() {
        $admin = User::where('name', 'admin')->first();
        if(empty($admin)) {
            $role =  Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();

            $admin = new User();
            $admin->username = 'admin';
            $admin->password = Hash::make('adminP@%%');
            $admin->save();

            $role->users()->attach($admin);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IM not sure why the saving role is not working maybe you can give more information but you can also try `$user->role()->create($role).`

But make sure the $role is an eloquent object.

When getting user roles you should use `$user->roles`